# How to use SSL in MariaDB datasource with quarkus?

Tags: ssl, mariadb, quarkus

I would like to connect to MariaDB database via SSL in Quarkus application. However, I cannot find a way how to define the SSL-related information in Quarkus application.

How to provide the certificate which is needed in database connection in Quarkus application?

Is it even possible?
If not, I assume that many would be interested in that feature.

I searched information from https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource but did not find anything regarding this.
MariaDB reference: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/using-tls-ssl-with-mariadb-java-connector/

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for it to not work. Just include what you need in your JDBC url.

Be aware though that if you are using native images, you should read this guide that will guide you through configuring everything properly: https://quarkus.io/guides/native-and-ssl .